# Is it acceptable to call overridable accessor and mutator methods within a constructor in PHP

Tags: php, constructor

In terms of constructors, due to the lack of accessors and mutators in PHP, I'm trying to emulate the same functionality by creating methods named setX() and getX() like so:

```
<?php

class Example {
  protected $message; // Nullable

  public function setMessage (Message $message = NULL) {
    $this->message = $message;
  }

  public function getMessage () {
    return $this->message;
  }
}

?>
```

I've read that setting properties by using the constructor should be identical to setting the properties using accessor and mutator methods.

But this leads to a problem in relation to constructors as I've read in a number of locations that you should not call overridable methods within a constructor because the invocation of an overridable method during object construction may result in the use of uninitialised data, leading to runtime exceptions or to unanticipated outcomes.

My question is, does the same rule apply, in that you should not call overloadable accessor and mutator methods, as shown the following example:

```
<?php

class Example {
  protected $message; // Nullable

  public function __construct (Message $message = NULL) {
    $this->setMessage($message);
  }

  public function setMessage (Message $message = NULL) {
    $this->message = $message;
  }

  public function getMessage () {
    return $this->message;
  }
}

?>
```

My sources for where I've read this information include:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/vstudio/ms229060%28v=vs.100%29.aspx
- https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/java/MET05-J.+Ensure+that+constructors+do+not+call+overridable+methods

Comment: Your sources are regarding the .NET framework and do not apply to php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the basis of what Ionuț G. Stan said, it isn't acceptable, and the following solution should be used:

```
<?php

class SuperClass {
  private $_color;

  public function __construct (Color $color) {
    $this->_setColor($color);
  }

  private function _setColor (Color $color) {
    $this->_color = $color;
  }

  public function setColor (Color $color) {
    $this->_setColor($color);
    echo "This is superclass! The color is: $this->_color";
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  private $_color = null;

  public function setColor (Color $color) {
    parent::setColor($color);
    echo "This is subclass! The color is: $this->_color";
  }
}
```

Comment: I'd make `_setColor` private and have the child class call `parent::setColor()` instead of `$this->_setColor`. It's confusing to have two types of setters.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does apply. Just port one of their examples to PHP and see what happens:

```
<?php

class SuperClass {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->doLogic();
  }

  public function doLogic() {
    echo "This is superclass!";
  }
}

class SubClass extends SuperClass {
  private $color = null;

  public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->color = "Red";
  }

  public function doLogic() {
    echo "This is subclass! The color is: $this->color";
  }
}

$bc = new SuperClass();
$sc = new SubClass();
```

#### Potential Solutions

1. make method `private`, i.e., non-overridable
2. make method `final`, i.e., non-overridable
3. call `parent::__construct` as the last statement in the child constructor

Comment: I can see where you are going there, so is there a solution?

Comment: @Bonner I've added a few potential solutions.

Comment: It is not a solution to have a private mutator and it is likely to cause problems making the mutator final too. I also think parent::__construct() should be the first statement in a child constructor.

Comment: @Bonner you can have two mutators, one overridable and one non-overridable, and have both the constructor and the overridable one call the non-overridable one.

Comment: I've provided a code example based on what you have mentioned, could you please review it and let me know if it is incorrect at all. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is acceptable.

When you can't/won't set the method to `final` there is just no other way 
that I know of to prevent this from happening.

I also do it, and if someone decides to extend the class its his responsibility to not break it.

It is certainly better than duplicating the setter logic to your constructor.

Comment: It does appear that Microsoft's code analysis, which is quite stringent, allows for this type of code without warning, providing the method is not virtual. However, when you think about overloading methods in PHP, those which are not private or final are virtual as they can be overloaded, and when overloading they have to match the signature of the parent method. I think the solution is possibly to have two methods, like suggested in another comment, so I'm going to experiment with this to see whether there is a solution.

Comment: By the definition I use any method that isnt ```final``` or ```private``` is ```virtual```. And by overloading you mean overriding? Because the overloading I know from java isn't possible in php...

Comment: I learn something new every day, didn't know there was a difference, but it seems so, turns out I did mean overriding. Thanks for making me aware of this.

Comment: You're very welcome. I never heard of securecoding.cert.org before so thx for that aswell.